# C#, Excel and converting data from cell to float

Tags: c#

I try convert value from the cell to float type, but time to time receive next error - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'float'"

```
 float b1=0;
 b1 = float.TryParse(ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5].Text, out b1);

 tried add .ToString = the same result 

 b1 = float.TryParse(ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5].Text.ToString(), out b1);
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[float.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx) is returning Boolean value, you can't assign it to float. you can use that boolean value for diplaying error message to user or log the issue. for example:

```
float b1=0;
if(!float.TryParse(ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5].Text, out b1))
{
    //conversion failed, show error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this:

```
float b1=0;
if(float.TryParse(ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5].Text.ToString(), out b1))
{
    tried add .ToString = the same result 
}
else
{
    throw exception;
}
```